# How to solve this ambiguous redirect error

Tags: linux, bash, cmd

I want to run a program (anchor) in all the .fa files in a directory, and append the output back into the input files (as next lines of original input content). For that I have tried:

```
for f in ./*.fa ; do ./anchor $f -d ./; done >> $f
```

and it gives the error:

```
bash: $f: ambiguous redirect
```

I understand bash is objecting to post the output content in the input file, but as I am recently migrating from windows system, there I'm doing it as:

```
for %F in ("*.fa") do anchor %F -d ./ >> %%F
```

which gives me the desired output.

Although this might seems strange to append output in input files, but how can I do that in shell?

Thanks

ps. I also try to use $$ in output redirection, but it forms a separate output file with different name and the original input content are also not merged in it.

Comment: `f` is only local to the `for` statement, you are redirecting to nothing, put it inside the `do` section.

Comment: `f` is not local; it retains the last assigned value after the loop.

Comment: The difference is that `>> $f` is processed *before* the loop runs, when `$f` likely expands to an empty string.

Comment: @chepner, oh yeah, my bad, looks like it isn't set before `>>`, so tries to open a non existent nothing. If you set it before the loop it doesn't produce an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the most logical way of doing it is to redirect from inside the loop instead, but not directly (thanks 123 for the comment: file cannot be input and output as the same time, maybe here it could work since windows loop seems to work, but let's not take useless risks...)

```
for f in ./*.fa ; do ./anchor $f -d ./ > /tmp/something; cat /tmp/something >> $f; done
```

BTW: I wouldn't dare trying to explain what your original code does, is `f` defined/when `$f` is evaluated (before or after entering the `for` loop).

My guess is that `$f` just *not* evaluated and considered as `$f` literally, which confuses `bash`.

At any rate, it's incorrect.

EDIT: the windows version

```
for %F in ("*.fa") do anchor %F -d ./ >> %%F
```

does the redirection *inside* the loop (unlike your unix attempt), and it's really surprising that it works because of windows file locking...

What could happen (not sure) is that windows doesn't try to append to the file before something is issued on standard output, and at that moment, the program has closed the file as input.

Comment: @123 what was I thinking... Well it _could_ work depending on what `anchor` does: if the program fully reads the file, and then issues the output it _could_ work (but would be risky at any rate). Edited.

Comment: Yeah, realised after i posted that it is append so may work, but you had deleted the answer.

Comment: I had deleted for editing. what _is_ strange is that it works for windows where files are locked (as opposed to Un*x), so if the windows version works, it means that my first version would work too (but it's not recommended since it depends on the program which is executed)